# Can I have the same EditText box on several Tab screens?

Tags: android

I am using three tabs for my application, with each tab showing a number of edittext boxes used for user input. For user convenience, I have some of the same edittext boxes on each screen so that the user doesn't have to go back to tab1 just to enter a value. For example, I have an edittext box on all three tab screens asking for the user's age. I have named the edittext boxes age1 on the tab1 screen, age2 on the tab2 screen, and age3 on the tab3 screen. Then I use code to read which of the three boxes have a value in it, I copy that value ionto the other two edittext boxes.

Is there a way to keep the same edittext box name in all three screens so that a value typed in one shows up in all three, and a single value can be retrieved with a single age.getValue() command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each tab nests an Activity, which is its own context.

Since an `EditText` requires a `Context` in its constructor, and will only exist in relation to that `Context`, you can't use it with multiple contexts.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need a activity for every tab
I think you cant add a view  twice (but its worth trying )

or you can  make a class that extends the editText class lets name it

make a static list in the class (theList)

in the constructor you add each instance to the list

oweride the on text changed method ( or something similar)
and set the text to every item in the list
{
for(EditText e:theList)
e.setText(this.getText());

}

i other words every instance will have the same text